# To find amount of data available in socket

Tags: c#, .net

Hai,
Without using "Socket.Available". How could we find the number of bytes available in socket in C#. Could anybody found help me.

Comment: Why would you need to do it without Socket.Available? Just curious as that may help

Answer (score 2):

`Socket.Available` is pretty much the closest you'll get here, but this still only tells you what is available *locally*, rather than what the socket is going to deliver. IMO, the most reliable approach here is to implement your network code so that you know how much data is *expected* (in advance, perhaps simply with a length marker), and then use (for example) async stream-reading to pull that data from the socket until either you have consumed exactly that much data, or you timeout. Then the answer to "how much more do I expect" is simply "how much did I expect originally" - "how much have I read so far".