# Method that returns number of bytes available in TCP/IP socket

Tags: c#

`socket.Available` does not work. Why?

Instead of `size` I need to use `socket.Available`. But it does not work. So I need a method that returns the number of bytes in socket.

```
void Receive(Socket socket, byte[] buffer, int offset, int size)
{
    //int sockAvail = socket.Available;  Here socket.Available always asigns 0 to sockAvail
    int received = 0;

    do
    {
       try
       {
          received += socket.Receive(buffer, offset + received, size - received, SocketFlags.None);
       }
       catch (Exception e) 
       { 
          Console.WriteLine(e.Message); 
       }

    } while (received < size);

    MessageBox.Show(socket.Available.ToString());
 }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? The number of bytes in the connection buffer, is that what you are looking for, or the number that has yet to be transmitted?

Comment: Is this any different to your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801361/to-find-amount-of-data-available-in-socket) ?

Comment: If you read all the available bytes in the `Receive` operation, it is likely `socket.Available` will be `0` or `false`  (not sure about the return type, sorry).

Comment: this is not `C`. c tag removed.

Answer (score 3):

Pass [`MSG_PEEK`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/recv) to `recv()`.

Comment: I need number of bytes yet to be transmitted in the socket.

Comment: How could the socket know that?  It knows how many that have been transmitted but have not been read from the application -- that's what Available is.  You might need to work at a higher-level to know that -- for example if you are transmitting HTTP, you could look at the content-length header to know how big the content is (it's optional, but that's just an example)

Answer (score 1):

`Socket.Available` has to be called before the `receive()` into the buffer, otherwise it's always 0.

Answer (score 0):

`socket.Available` is for blocking sockets.  With asynchronous reads, you just read what you can and then go back into a select to be told when it's ok to read more.

Comment: socket.Available returns integer but before reading the received bytes it shows 0

Comment: When do socket.Available does asign its value to the variable

Comment: eg: int s = socket.Available;

Answer (score 0):

It does work. It just doesn't meet your expectations. Your expectations are wrong. Adjust them.